# Efficient looping of a page with multi subpages and storing all of them in one variable?

Tags: r, iteration, html

lets say i have as a string the following page:

```
X <- "http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/Glasgow.html?sortType=6&maxPrice=50000&displayPropertyType=flats&numberOfPropertiesPerPage=50&index=0"
```

now i would like to iterate it by the last adjacent element

`"index=0"`.

It will be incremented by 50 at every iteration lets say until 500. So I am having 11 strings now with the differences at the end:

```
"index=0"
"index=50"
"index=100"
...
"index=500"
```

My question is how to nicely and quickly store each string to the same variable so after finish I could use that variable as an parameter for further data extraction by doing greps, gsubs and regexps ?
I mean I want to download the whole page source by each of that string which is simply a pointer to a website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a web **scraper** f?

In my personal experience, the best way is to find the "next page" button in the page and parse next URL from it. This way you are emulating user clicks and your program will know exactly where to stop.

I also store already processed urls, in order to prevent an infinit loop.